# Unknown PowerShell-Script with dubious content: Malware?

Tags: powershell, malware

I found a script named `5cfdf61c454c1fc5e9f0fcad2d12d5ef.ps1` on my computer:

```cs
$pyfwthc = # this is just a TON of random letters and numbers didnt wanna waste the space and its probably not important (encrypted maybe?)
$sstring = ConvertTo-SecureString $pyfwthc
$script = (New-Object system.Management.Automation.PSCredential("pyfwthc", $sstring)).GetNetworkCredential().Password
Invoke-Expression $script
```

Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: Well yes, that’s a malware dropper. Do include the string though.

Comment: Turns out i'm not able to do that because the question would be 1619 digits too long

Comment: Could paste the contents of pyfwthc into a Pastebin and reference that url?

Comment: What is the path to that file? / Where did you find it?

Comment: You need to extract value of `$script` to see, what this thing is actually doing. Without that all I can say: this run some on purpose hidden obfuscated script. That is something legitimate scripts rare doing.

Comment: @HelpingHand Seeing `$pyfwthc` have no purpose. String is encrypted with user specific secret, so you will not be able to decrypt it anyway.

Comment: It’s not a password. The “password” is the actual code that runs, in encrypted form. That’s why it’s the most important part of this snippet.

Comment: @PetSerAl after performing some tests I can tell you that the .GetNetworkCredential().Password on the 3rd line does decrypt the string. It would have to in order to run the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

- The first line stores that large string in a variable called "pyfwthc".
- The second line "Converts encrypted standard strings to secure strings", this is done to protect the password:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-5.1
- The third line creates a PowerShell credential that can be used to authenticate other commands from a PowerShell script without exposing the password. Then it pulls out the password from that credential. This converts the encrypted string in to plain text.
- The fourth line runs the "password" as a command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-5.1

UPDATE:
As other users have pointed out it is running the password string as a command. You want to dump the value of $script to a file so you can see what it is running:

Remove the last line from the script and run:

```
echo $script > this_is_the_script.file
```

Comment: It does not print the credential. It *executes* the command(s) that’s in the encrypted password string. It *is* a malware dropper.